# How to get "Total number of messages on the IoT Hub exceeded the allocated quota" message from Azure iot sdk c

Tags: azure-iot-sdk

I'm using Azure iot sdk c, sometimes my iothub service can reach to maximum quota, I can see connection error or backend can't get data, but not able to obviously check if the connection error is because of maximum quota reached.

In the meantime, I can see below logs from SDK, but not sure if up layer can get this messages:

`{true,2,NULL,true,* {* {amqp:resource-limit-exceeded,Total number of messages on the IoT Hub exceeded the allocated quota. Increase units for this hub to increase the quota. For more information on quota, please refer to: https://aka.ms/iothubthrottling,{[com.microsoft:tracking-id:6c35054a81b04a5a81ae292a6ab0a7c1-G:0-TimeStamp:03/12/2022 07:46:09],[com.microsoft:is-filtered:true]}}},NULL}`

I am keen to know if application layer can get this reason from ampq response.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question myself. MS team added the support in the latest version of the Azure IoT SDK C. that's a fantastic support. appreciate!